# How to use Single Sign On in a Vaadin application

Tags: authentication, spring-security, authorization, single-sign-on, vaadin

I have a Vaadin 7 application that needs to **use SSO** (or a better kind of enterprise sign on method?) to **authorize users through an LDAP directory**. I also need to **use groups** or **"roles"** to differ between users and **what they are allowed to access** in my application. I am new to both login processes and Vaadin, and all I have right now is a working login form in my application that authorizes users against a fake "AD class" that I made myself.

So...

- Where and how do I even start?
- I read something about portlets and Liferay in this context. Is it even possible to achieve my goals without using Liferay or portlets?
- Are there any good Vaadin addons that can help me with this?
- Can I use Spring security for this? (I am using xpoft SpringVaadinIntegration addon and I know it handles roles for example)...

If I sound lost, it's probably because I am. I will gladly read up on this, if I even knew where to start. Please help me chop this monolithic blob of confusion into smaller pieces =)

Comment: Do you realy mean SSO, or just authenticate/authorize against active directory?

Comment: SSO in combination with a/a. If I understand SSO correctly, the Windows login would be enough to make you a/a to the application? I.e. the Windows logon process will get a TGT which the application then uses to create a ST which is then used to a/a said user in the Authentication Server (LDAP).

Comment: I have to do the same as you, but I just need to authenticate against active directory. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I feel you brother. I thought to find a simple Servlet Filter which redirects to a login page hosted by a SSO server which I can run in-house. Instead I found SAML - a goulash of abstract terms with no working tutorial whatsoever. Spring SAML tutorial at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html works but a) I have no idea what I just did, b) SSO Circle page looks so hideous it borderlines with virus spoofing page. JOSSO - no idea what it even solves. I thought Kerberos to be difficult but it looks super easy compared to SAML.

Answer (score 2):

SSO with windows login only works in the intranet and it requires the use of kerberos or ntlm.

You can use a library like waffle to integrate things.

Look here:

- [Link #1](https://github.com/dblock/waffle/blob/master/README.md)
- [Link #2](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/905304)